# ebay api find out number of listings found

Tags: html, request, ebay-api

I am trying to build a simple web application that tells the use how many ebay search results there is (like the google-fight.com but on ebay).

I got a developer account and know how to pass requests to the api and parse the result via JavaScript. My problem is that I can't find out to how to know the number of listing provided. All I find is:
`paginationInput.entriesPerPage` and `paginationInput.pageNumber`
the max value of each of them is 100 what can indicate for up to 10000 search results.

Theoretically I can jump to the 100 pageNumber and check how many entries there there and then calculate (99*100+number of entries on page). Of course its not good solution it takes a lot of calls and not effective with products with more then 10000 listings.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not indicated in your question which eBay operation you are using I'm going to assume that you are calling findItemsAdvanced. If this is the case the total number of found items will be returned in the  [paginationOutput.totalEntries](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Response.paginationOutput.totalEntries) element.